# Is Type III ANCOVA warranted?

Tags: r, ancova

I'm running the following ANCOVA:

```
m1 <- aov(formula = Rate ~ Treatment * Species * Weight, data = Data)
car::ANOVA(m1, type = 2)
```

My design is a bit unbalanced so I ran a type II ANOVA. I got these results:

```
Response: Rate
                                         Sum Sq Df F value   Pr(>F)   
Treatment                                 8.294  2  2.1963 0.120538   
Species                                   22.110  1 11.7097 0.001157 **
Weight                                    6.943  1  3.6771 0.060180 . 
Treatment:Species                         1.016  2  0.2692 0.764987   
Treatment:Weight                          15.985  2  4.2329 0.019320 * 
Species:Weight                            0.058  1  0.0308 0.861229   
Treatment:Species:Weight                  3.378  2  0.8945 0.414477   
Residuals                               107.628 57
```

Based on [this article](https://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/anova-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/), my understanding is that you run a type II ANOVA first if your data is unbalanced. If the interaction is significant, then you should run a type III ANOVA. Is that correct?

Based on the significant interaction between Treatment and Weight, is a type III ANOVA warranted? I wasn't sure if Type III should be used for significant interactions between categorical and continuous variables or not, or whether that only applies to interactions between two categorical variables.

When I run a type III ANOVA, the significant interaction between Treatment and Weight disappears and changes the conclusions substantially:

```
type3 <- list(Treatment = contr.sum, Species = contr.sum)
m2 <- aov(formula = Rate ~ Treatment * Species * Weight, data = Data, contrasts = type3)
m2 <- car::Anova(m2, type = 3)
```

```
Response: Rate
                                         Sum Sq Df  F value  Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)                             286.377  1 151.6654 < 2e-16 ***
Treatment                                10.370  2   2.7461 0.07268 .  
Species                                  3.934  1   2.0832 0.15440    
Weight                                   2.174  1   1.1514 0.28777    
Treatment:Species                        3.590  2   0.9506 0.39257    
Treatment:Weight                         5.670  2   1.5015 0.23147    
Species:Weight                           0.302  1   0.1600 0.69065    
Treatment:Species:Weight                 3.378  2   0.8945 0.41448    
Residuals                               107.628 57
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You also need to center the continuous predictor: `weight - mean(weight)` for the type 3 sums of squares. (Think of this as analogous to using the sum contrast for categorical variables.) That being said, I'm not sure why you are looking into type 3 sums of squares. Have you looked at how well the model fits the data? Is rate a non-negative variable that perhaps could suggest a different model? Just a couple of things that might be more interesting to do than type 3 anova.